# How can we search specific amino acid on PyMol?

Tags: pymol

I would like to know if there is any way to click or any command that I can use to find a particular amino acid sequence in PyMol. Now it is quite time-consuming that I have to scroll over the length of protein to get the target site.

Please let me know if there is any button or command I can use for this purpose.

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in command line.

The [`select`](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Select) command is there for that purpose. Use the [selection algebra](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Selection_Algebra) to restrict your search. Or you can also use [selection macros](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Selection_Macros).